# How to Resize Shiny textAreaInput label width

Tags: r, shiny

Using these parameters I can easily resize the width of the input box however when my label is particularly long, it goes to a new line despite the width of the box being wider than the allowed space for the label line.

```
textAreaInput(inputId, label, value = "", width = NULL, height = NULL,
  cols = NULL, rows = NULL, placeholder = NULL, resize = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The general solution would be specifying the width of the input container via CSS, and not via the `width` argument of `textAreaInput()`.

Of course if you have other input elements in your app (and I assume you do), you'll have to adjust the CSS in accordance with them.

Working example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$style(".form-group.shiny-input-container { width: 600px; }"),

    textAreaInput(
      inputId = "txt", 
      label = "long label long label long label long label long label"
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to resize the label while not resizing the text area?